# Couldn't find User without an ID again and again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi guys i've some problem with RoR. I try to define a current user like that

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end

end
```

that's my error : Couldn't find User without an ID

I don't know why... I've an user_id in my BBD.

Comment: Check if `session[:user_id]` is empty

Comment: What does `BBD` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting this error, because there is no :user_id in your session. Try:

```
@current_user ||= session[:user_id] && User.find(session[:user_id])
```

or

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
```

Note however that if there is no key, rails will try to fetch user from database every time you call `current_user` (since `@current_user` is nil). Best way to avoid it is:

```
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user) 
  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

This will allow you to cache nil result as well.

Comment: Thanks to you ! :) Now i'll try to determinate which user is an admin or not. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution were

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:user_id] && User.find(session[:user_id])
en
```

OR

```
def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```